# Android Toolbar collapseMode issue

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have an Issue making " toolbar with Title text " Not to Collapse while scrolling upwards in CollapsingToolbarLayout.

I have tried a few tweaks, by using **app:layout_collapseMode="none"** as attribute in my android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar but its not working. Maybe there is a problem with my layout.

**Below is what i am trying to achieve.**

[image: Trying to Achieve]

But when i scroll to the top, the **Toolbar** also collapse, and the tabBar also scrolls inside, and become non-visible. below is what i have now.

[image: what i have now]

**This is my Layout Code**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">



        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#20000000" />

            </FrameLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="none"
                >
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Application Title"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>




        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>



        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/detail_tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"

                android:background="#00000000"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="#3498db"
                app:tabTextColor="#000" />
            />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#333"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Dependencies**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1"
    compile "com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.1"
    compile "com.android.support:design:22.2.1"
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'

}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try this...

You have to use **app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"** instead of **app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"**  inside the **CollapsingToolbarLayout**

and use **app:layout_collapseMode="pin"** inside the **toolbar**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#20000000" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Application Title"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Answer (score 8):

In your toolbar do this:

```
app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
```

> **pin** is used for pinning the layout to top when the collapsing toolbar
>   layout scrolls
>
> **parallax** is used for hiding the layout when collapsing toolbar scrolls
>   to top