# Collapsing Toolbar and ImageView - toolbar is not showing

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have Collapsing `Toolbar` with `ImageView` and `Toolbar` (which contais this three lines icon for side drawer menu for example). `ImageView` is collapsing just like I want but... Toolbar is not showing at all.When I remove `ImageView` everything is fine (I mean Toolbar is showing normally).

**This is my code:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" tools:openDrawer="start">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />




            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="380dp"
                android:layout_height="320dp"
                android:background="@drawable/plant2"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_layout"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32853112/android-toolbar-collapsemode-issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed" inside the CollapsingToolbarLayout

and use app:layout_collapseMode="pin" inside the toolbar

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
        app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#20000000" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Application Title"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```