# Toolbar within LinearLayout pinned inside CollapsingToolbarLayout but pushed upwards during scroll

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I would like to have an advertisement displayed just about the toolbar. So, I have to orginize vertically in a linear way my adTopView and Toolbar inside LinearLayout with orientation="vertical". Because if I put Toolbar directly in CollapsingToolbarLayout in stays in place but I cannot put Toolbar directly under the banner (LinearLayout) because CollapsingToolbarLayout is just FrameLayout.

The problem is that Toolbar although is pinned with app:layout_collapseMode="pin" but is get pushed upwards and become non-visible while I scroll up.

Just like mentioned in on of the last comments "Now It retains as i scroll up gradually, BUT as soon as i scroll to the position of the Toolbar, the toolbar get pushed upwards and become non-visible." of the folloing question:
[Android Toolbar collapseMode issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32853112/android-toolbar-collapsemode-issue#comment53540027_32853146)

**Here is my CoordinatorLayout**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/rootCoordinatorLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/background">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/lowerAppBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="@dimen/design_appbar_elevation"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            tools:targetApi="lollipop">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:titleEnabled="false"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/scrollableImage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsingToolLinearLayout"
                style="@style/Toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/adTopView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"/>
                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/toolbarWrapper"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/primary">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                        style="@style/Toolbar"
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        app:theme="@style/ToolbarStyle"/>

                    <TextView style="@style/Badge.Toolbar"
                        android:id="@+id/badge"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        tools:text="42"
                        android:text="42"
                        android:visibility="gone"/>
                </FrameLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/adWrappedContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/background"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: try `android:fitSystemWindow="true"`

Comment: @d1vivek681065 on which element? I'm acually use android:fitsSystemWindows="true" for AppBarLayout

Comment: try in Coordinator layout or in all if dont work...:)