# Placing Recylerview beneath transparent actionbar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-actionbar

I currently have a fragment with a `recylerView` and an `actionBar` that is transparent. I am trying to create a space at the top of my `recylerView` so that my `actionBar` isn't immediately overlapping my `recylerView` when viewing the top of the recylerView. This is the effect I am trying to create (taken from default gallery app):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvCBi.jpg

This is what I currently have in my own app:

[image]

How do I get that little white space at the top before my recylerView so that my transparent actionBar isn't overlapping the topmost recylerView row immediately?

This is the relevant code:

**ActivityMain.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);


    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = FragmentAlbumGallery.newInstance();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, Constants.FRAGMENT_ALBUMS_GALLERY).commit();


    }
}
```

**FragmentAlbumGallery.java:**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycler_gallery, container, false);
    mAlbumRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    mAlbumRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2));
    //onResume() gets called here. No need to set up adapter since we do it there
   // setupAdapter();
    return v;
}
```

**activity_fragment.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">
</FrameLayout>
```

**fragment_recyler_gallery.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ActivityGallery"/>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding padding top on your recyclerview equal to the height of the actionbar?

Comment: What does your Activity XML look like?

Comment: Yes, I actually have! When I add the padding to the top of my recylerview, the actionbar is no longer transparent!

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://cyrilmottier.com/2013/05/24/pushing-the-actionbar-to-the-next-level/) tutorial.

Comment: Your question does not have the full code, it does not tell how are you setting Toolbar in your Activity.

Comment: Solved!!! I needed to put the RecyclerView inside a NestedScrollView. Turns out I was only scrolling within the RecyclerView instead of scrolling on the entire FrameLayout. Hopefully this saves someone a lot of time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `View` and `RecyclerView` under it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#c4c4c4" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response! This is the result I get: https://gph.is/2MNtGxw. How do I pin that gray area to the top so that it doesn't scroll?

Comment: That is an another issue which you should open a new thread-question but i answer hope i can help : That's a `Toolbar` so, you're gonna need `CoordinatorLayout` + `Toolbar` and this line for `Toolbar`: app:layout_collapseMode="pin" Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32853390/4409113 and so much more on SO.

Comment: Solved!!! I needed to put the RecyclerView inside a NestedScrollView. Turns out I was only scrolling within the RecyclerView instead of scrolling on the entire FrameLayout. Hopefully this saves someone a lot of time!

Comment: Ow, so you were trying to achieve scrolling behavior. Well yeah, you could do that too which is not related to this thread. Please use **Ask question** for further questions.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to put my RecyclerView inside a NestedScrollView like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@null" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

The issue I was having was that I was only scrolling within my RecyclerView instead of the entire fragment.

Comment: However; **Question title:** Placing `Recylerview` beneath transparent actionbar? And now, *scrolling within my RecyclerView instead of the entire fragment*. Not related to this thread i'm afraid tho.